# Why is AcceptedAnswerId null for a question that has an accepted answer?

Tags: support, data-explorer

This StackExchange [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/500244) attempts to get the first 10 unanswered bounty questions:

```
SELECT TOP 10 Posts.AnswerCount, Posts.AcceptedAnswerId, Posts.Id AS [Post Link]
FROM Posts
    JOIN Votes ON Votes.PostId = Posts.Id
      and Posts.PostTypeId = 1 -- questions
      and Votes.BountyAmount > 0
      and Posts.AnswerCount = 0
      and Posts.AcceptedAnswerId IS NULL
ORDER BY Posts.CreationDate DESC
```

...but it returns a list of questions that already have accepted answers:

[image]

I would've expected `AnswerCount` and `AcceptedAnswerId` to be nonzero for those answered questions. Why are these posts showing up in my results? (I think it's a bug, but maybe my query is wrong.)

Comment: Didn't find that dupe yesterday somehow, sorry about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no bug and nothing is wrong with the query.

SEDE is not using live data. As written in its [help page](https://data.stackexchange.com/help):

> The data is updated early every Sunday morning around 3:00 UTC

And SEDE homepage itself contains:

> [image]

So answers accepted after the last update occured, won't show up.

That said, SEDE isn't ideal for dealing with those things. You better use the built in search, which got advanced search operators. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=active&q=hasnotice%3a1%20hasaccepted%3a0%20answers%3a0) search appears to return what you want, and using the following:

- `hasnotice:1` to bring only questions with a notice - this add some noise, but quite minor.
- `hasaccepted:0` to omit questions with accepted answer.

- `answers:0` to bring back only questions without any answers.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer and search tip (which I'll definitely use going forward).